# Why last command in chef recipe executing first?

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, chef-recipe

i run it in kitchen vagrant centos-72 Chef 12.19.36

in metadata.rb 

`depends 'rabbitmq', '~> 3.0'`

run_list that  i try

```
 "recipe[rabbitmq]",
 "recipe[rabbitmq::mgmt_console]",
 "recipe[rabbitmq::user_management]",
 "recipe[mycookbook::myrecipe]"
```

myrecipe is

```
chef_gem 'rabbitmq_http_api_client' do
  version                    '1.8.0'
  action                     :install
end

require "rabbitmq/http/client"
endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:15672"
client = RabbitMQ::HTTP::Client.new(endpoint, :username => "user", :password => "321")
client.declare_exchange("myvhost", "myexchange", durable: true, type: "direct")
```

Without myrecipe all is ok.
But If I add myrecipe to the end of the runlist, then its content begin to run before the rest of the recipes, and of course, a get 

`Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:15672 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 15672)`

Now i solve this with this code, but I dont like this, and dont understand why declare_exchange run before rabbitmq install

```
include_recipe 'rabbitmq'

rabbitmq_plugin 'rabbitmq_management' do
  action :enable
end

rabbitmq_user 'user' do
  password "321"
  action :add
end

rabbitmq_vhost 'myvhost' do
  action :add
end

rabbitmq_user 'user' do
  vhost 'myvhost'
  permissions ".* .* .*"
  action :set_permissions
end


rabbitmq_user 'user' do
  tag 'administrator'
  action :set_tags
end

rabbitmq_user "guest" do
  action :delete
  notifies :run, 'ruby_block[declare_rmq_exchange]'
end

chef_gem 'rabbitmq_http_api_client' do
  version                    '1.8.0'
  action                     :install
end

require "rabbitmq/http/client"
endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:15672"

ruby_block 'declare_rmq_exchange' do
  block do
    client = RabbitMQ::HTTP::Client.new(endpoint, :username => "user", :password => "321")
    client.declare_exchange("myvhost", "myexchange", durable: true, type: "direct")
  end
  action :nothing
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the [two-phase model](https://coderanger.net/two-pass/) of chef-client. First, the ruby code is executed (*compile phase*) and afterwards the implementations of the defined resources (like `rabbitmq_user` or `chef_gem`) are execute (*convergence phase*).

As your call to `RabbitMQ::HTTP::Client.new` is executed in the compile phase, it is executed first prior to the user setup.

Wrap this code within a [`ruby_block`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html) resource so that it is executed in the expected order.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand my mistake! It's work!